# jQuery: Converting "Filter" to "Contains" for More Matches of a Text String

Tags: jquery, html, css, filter, contains

How can I edit my jQuery so that I can use the *contains* method... so that all DIVs that have a matching string, are shown? I currently have the following code working (*jQuery 2.1.0*), for DIVs to appear (*show*), when the input entered into a search box by a user matches the beginning of the string (*filter*) in a DIV:

```
$('.bunnyHolder').hide();

$("#bunnySearch").bind("keyup", function() {
    var alString = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var items = $(".bunnyName");

    // Hide investments wrapper
    items.parent().hide();

    // Show investments matching input
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        items.filter(function () {return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(alString) == 0;}).parent().show();
    }
    else {
        $('.bunnyHolder').hide();
    }
});
```

Here is the **JSFiddle**:

http://jsfiddle.net/zpL9x/

Right now, when a user enters "bunny" (case insensitive) into the search box, only the DIV that starts with "bunny" appears... what I want is for all DIVs to appear, since they all contain "bunny". Here are my DIVs:

```
<div id="results">
    <div class="bunnyHolder">
        <span class="bunnyName">Bunny</span>
    </div>
    <div class="bunnyHolder">
        <span class="bunnyName">Easter Bunny</span>
    </div>
    <div class="bunnyHolder">
        <span class="bunnyName">Godzilla Bunny</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

To repeat: how can I edit my jQuery so that I can use the *contains* method... so that all DIVs that have a matching string, are shown? And, is there a way to make the matching string **bold** (only the word "bunny")?

I've read many StackOverflow posts today, but do not understand how to make the *contains* method work with my code. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `.contains()`. The `.indexOf()` method returns the index at which the matching text starts, or -1 if the text isn't found. So you can change

```
$(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(alString) == 0;
```

to this:

```
$(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(alString) > -1;
```

---

The bolding will be a bit more complex. Every time a key is pressed, you'll need to iterate all the items and `unwrap` any `b` tags. Then for each item to be shown, I would probably just use a regex to replace the search text with the same text wrapped in `b` tags.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I can accept the answer in 10 minutes, and I will. Also... is there any chance that making the text string which is chosen to **bold** is easy?

Comment: If I spend time trying to understand this post http://bit.ly/1hxPdDj will I be able to arrive at the **bolding** that I seek? Is the linked post in this comment a good place to start?

Comment: Something like that.. Have you considered trying to use the [jquery ui autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)?

Comment: I did consider it, thanks, but it was just easier for what I wanted to  show/hide DIVs that weren't connected to the input field. The input field is really nowhere near where the DIVs are in my actual project. for the JSFiddle I took a lot of styling out, in order to get to the heart of with what I was having trouble. Thanks again!